# null in repeated rows of PLSQL cursor output

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm having difficulties in explaining my problem. I have made a PLSQL procedure, this takes data from multiple tables with a simple query, then the output is sent to a cursor which then output the result as a xml, which is then finally printed as the following excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBvAY.jpg)

What I want is to put null in the values under the red rectangles cause they have the same "FATTURA" name of the row before them to not repeat the same field over and over, leaving only the last field which is always different. How can i do it? I can put also the Procedure if someone wanna gave a look

To explain better I have this:

```
values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 23.22); 
values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 18.22);
values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 12.23);
values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 14.50);
values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 21.22); 
values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 17.22);
values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 1.23);
values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 145.10);
```

my final output (that i need to print in xml and then excel, i'm using Oracle Application) should be this:

```
CODICE   NOME             DATA_FATTURA  TOTAL
------  ---------------   ------------  ----
10002   MANSANI, Luigi    01.12.2008    23.22
  /          /                 /        18.22
  /          /                 /        12.23
  /          /                 /        14.50
10004   MANSANI, LUIGI    01.12.2009    21.22
  /          /                 /        17.22
  /          /                 /        1.23
  /          /                 /        145.10
```

where the "/" should be a null value, empty cell in the final excel file

Comment: without code no one here will be able to help you... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly define the order of your rows.
Here's the solution using the order surrogate `(ORDER BY rownum)`.
But while it seems to produce correct results, the order is actually not guaranteed by Oracle to be the same every time.
Make sure your table has a primary key and make it a part of the order clause.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN lag(nome) over(ORDER BY rownum)=nome THEN '/' ELSE to_char(codice) END codice
, CASE WHEN lag(nome) over(ORDER BY rownum)=nome THEN '/' ELSE to_char(nome) END nome
, CASE WHEN lag(nome) over(ORDER BY rownum)=nome THEN '/' ELSE to_char(data_fattura) END data_fattura
, VALUE
FROM test
```

**output**

```
10002 MANSANI, Luigi  01-DEC-08 23.22
/     /               /         18.22
/     /               /         12.23
/     /               /         14.5
10004 MANSANI, LUIGI  01-DEC-09 21.22
/     /               /         17.22
/     /               /         1.23
/     /               /         145.1
```

Comment: wow, thanks for the suggestion, it worked flawlessly, and the code is really simple and short. I would have never thought to use the case when this way

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table name as `fattura` with three columns `codice`, `nome` and `data_fattura`, you may try to run the following statements :

```
create table fattura
( codice       int,
  nome         varchar2(100),
  data_fattura date,
  total        number(10,2)
);

insert all 
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 23.22) 
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 18.22)
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 12.23)
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10002,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2008','dd.mm.yyyy'), 14.50)
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 21.22) 
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 17.22)
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 1.23)
  into fattura(codice,nome,data_fattura,total) values(10004,'MANSANI, Luigi',to_date('01.12.2009','dd.mm.yyyy'), 145.10)
select * from dual;

select  rn,
    first_value(codice ignore nulls) over (partition by codice order by codice rows between rn+1 following and unbounded following) codice,
    first_value(nome ignore nulls) over (partition by codice order by codice rows between rn+1 following and unbounded following) nome,
    first_value(data_fattura ignore nulls) over (partition by codice order by codice rows between rn+1 following and unbounded following) data_fattura,
    total
  from  
(  
 select codice, nome,data_fattura, total,
        row_number() over( partition by codice, nome, data_fattura order by codice ) rn 
   from fattura
);


RN   CODICE   NOME             DATA_FATTURA    TOTAL
--   ------  ---------------   ------------  -------    
1     10002   MANSANI, Luigi    01.12.2008     23,22
2                                              18,22
3                                              12,23
4                                              14,50
1     10004   MANSANI, Luigi    01.12.2009     21,22
2                                              17,22
3                                               1,23
4                                             145,10
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2b512/26)

Comment: thanks for the reply (that I'm trying to study, I'm not and advanced user) but I think you misinterpreted what I have to do, check the question above I just edited

Comment: @FrancescoBaldacchini Ciao amico, prego. I've changed the solution as you'd like.